# How to Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to turn an HTML 5 template into a Wordpress theme. The jQuery/Javascript combo seems not to be working, what should I do? (I just used 
    `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` 
so the .js files are correctly linked)

Comment: ?????? Please, explain better.

Comment: Both Javascript and jQuery aren't working, even if they are correctly included in the page

Comment: Why don't you post code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just paste this in your functions.php file. It will automatically add jQuery in your theme.

```
function wcs_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcs_scripts_styles' );
```

WordPress automatically include jquery from it's location. You do not need to upload jquery on your theme.
additionally you can also add more scripts lile this.

```
function wcs_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'new-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/new-script.js', 'jquery', NULL, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcs_scripts_styles' );
```

In this code `new-script.js` is in theme\your-theme\js\ folder. You can similarly add more js files like that.

Comment: @Daniele you should need the `wp_head()` function called inside the `<head></head>` tag to work with enqueueing.